# CSS div not floating next to a centered div

Tags: html, css, center

I am a bit of a css noob, so I apologize in advance if my vocabulary isn't the best when it comes to this topic. I am working on a website, with a ticker div vertically centered inside another div. I am attempting to float a sidebar to the right of this, but the sidebar won't sit right next to the div, it instead pushes it down.

```
#rightnav{
background-color: blue;
width: 250px;
float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/walter4/mw23L/1/ 
If you could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you floating the other div?

Comment: Don't use `<marquee>`...it's been deprecated from HTML5 as an element

Comment: That's because, "tickeroutline" div is being inline and takes whole line for him.

Comment: Could you please review my answer and accept it if it is helpful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#tickeroutline {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 40px;
    width: 750px;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}
```

You just need to add `float: left;` to `#tickeroutline`